# Where can I find the Lightning Usage App?

Tags: performance, app, usagemetrics

I'm looking to use the Lightning Usage App to get metrics on my app, but I cannot find it. The [Lightning Experience Performance Optimization](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning-experience-performance-optimization/measure-lightning-experience-performance-and-experience-page-time-ept) says, "To open the Lightning Usage App, click the App Launcher and search for Lightning Usage," but Lightning Usage is not found nor is it listed when I click "View All." It's also not listed in the Lightning Experience App Manager in Settings.

How do I enable this app?

Comment: are you an admin? have you checked that your profile has visibility to the Custom App (Lightning Usage App).

Comment: I am an admin, but the Lighting Usage App isn't even listed in the Lightning Experience App Manager in Settings, so if it weren't available to my user profile, I can add it.

Comment: and this is production? It might be relevant to add what type of Org edition you have.

Comment: No, it is in a dev pro sandbox. Is it only available in production? We're trying to optimize the app before we get to production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Lightning Usage Application is only available in production.This was highlighted in the release notes when it came out in [Winter '19](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_lex_lightning_usage_app.htm).

[image]

You can vote for [this idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000U46iQAC) asking for it to be available in Sandboxes.

In terms of testing your application performance, you can use the first method mentioned in the trailhead.

Add the Experienced Page Time (EPT) counter to your page. You can do this in one of two ways

1. Enabling `Lightning component Debug Mode` from Setup
2. Add `?eptVisible=1` to the end of your url.

The difference being that #1 may impact performance as caching is disabled, but gives you the page load time and the network bandwidth. #2 displays the page load counter but won't display network bandwidth (and less impact on performance).