Troubleshooting missing metrics in the Lightning Usage app
As an admin, I am unable to locate the metrics for Active Licenses and Login Metrics when browsing the Lightning Usage app. Is there anything specific that needs to be updated? Could someone please provide guidance on how to make these indicators appear?


Have you checked this? - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/342088/where-can-i-find-the-lightning-usage-app?rq=1

yes, I'm in Production, just not sure why Active Licenses and Login Metrics are disappeared
